# How do you repeat on filtering datasets and then running regressions without writing out individual code?

Tags: r, filter, statistics, repeat, tidy

How do you repeat on filtering datasets and then running regressions without writing out individual code?

I want to run a linear regression on the `mtcars` data where the data are all of mtcars, the IV is `mtcars$am`, and the DV is `mtcars$mpg`. I then want to use the grouping variable `mtcars$gear` to create 3 datasets where `mtcars$gear` is 3, 4, or 5, and then runs the regressions again with these 3 datasets separately.

The long process that I currently used is below.

Unique values of variables of interest:

```
## variables of interets
unique(mtcars$mpg)
# ---- NOTE: DV is mpg
unique(mtcars$am)
# ---- NOTE: IV is mpg
unique(mtcars$gear)
# ---- NOTE: grouping variable is gear
```

Here is the baseline code I used for the regression:

```
## linear regression with all data
lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars)
```

I then used the `filter()` command in the `tidyverse` package to create 3 datasets, where `mtcars$gear` is 3, 4, or 5

```
### list of filtered datasets
str(mtcars__gear_is_3)
str(mtcars__gear_is_4)
str(mtcars__gear_is_5)
```

I then created 3 regressions with the same basic structure as the base regression above, but with different datasets connected with different `mtcars$gear` levels.

```
#### when mtcars__gear_is_3 is dataset used
lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_3 <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars__gear_is_3)
summary(lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_3)

#### when mtcars__gear_is_4 is dataset used
lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_4 <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars__gear_is_4)
summary(lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_4)

#### when mtcars__gear_is_5 is dataset used
lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_5 <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars__gear_is_5)
summary(lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_5)
```

This seems to work, but it also seems to be a lot of code. I feel this could be accomplished with more concise code. I want to know if I can speed this process up by writing code that:
(A) creates different datasets in a shorter way using the `tidyverse` filter method
(B) creates different regressions in a shorter way that just swaps the dataset names when appropriate
without having to write all of the code the long way.

Here are my questions:
(1) Is this possible to do in R in general?
(2) Is this possible with datasets?
(2.1) If so, how?
(3) Is this possible with regressions?
(3.1) If so, how?

====================

Here is my R code that I used to complete this task the long way

```
# How do you repeat on filtering datasets and then running regressions in R without writing out individual code?

## dataset of interest
mtcars

### info about dataset
head(mtcars)
str(mtcars)
columns(mtcars)

## variables of interets
unique(mtcars$mpg)
# ---- NOTE: DV is mpg
unique(mtcars$am)
# ---- NOTE: IV is mpg
unique(mtcars$gear)
# ---- NOTE: grouping variable is gear

## linear regression with all data
lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars)

## filter data based on mtcars$gear

### loads tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

### when mtcars$gear == 3

#### creates filtered dataset
# ---- NOTE: starting dataset - mtcars
# ---- NOTE: ending dataset - mtcars__gear_is_3
# ---- NOTE: filter variable - gear
# ---- NOTE: filter variable value(s) - 3

##### starting dataset
str(mtcars)

##### unique values of starting dataset$filter
unique(mtcars$gear)

##### filters data into post-filter dataset
mtcars__gear_is_3 <- filter(mtcars, (gear == "3"))

##### turns post-filter dataset into data frame
mtcars__gear_is_3 <- data.frame(mtcars__gear_is_3)

##### post-filter dataset
str(mtcars__gear_is_3)

##### unique values of post-filter dataset$filter
unique(mtcars__gear_is_3$gear)

### when mtcars$gear == 4

#### creates filtered dataset
# ---- NOTE: starting dataset - mtcars
# ---- NOTE: ending dataset - mtcars__gear_is_4
# ---- NOTE: filter variable - gear
# ---- NOTE: filter variable value(s) - 4

##### starting dataset
str(mtcars)

##### unique values of starting dataset$filter
unique(mtcars$gear)

##### filters data into post-filter dataset
mtcars__gear_is_4 <- filter(mtcars, (gear == "4"))

##### turns post-filter dataset into data frame
mtcars__gear_is_4 <- data.frame(mtcars__gear_is_4)

##### post-filter dataset
str(mtcars__gear_is_4)

##### unique values of post-filter dataset$filter
unique(mtcars__gear_is_4$gear)

### when mtcars$gear == 5

#### creates filtered dataset
# ---- NOTE: starting dataset - mtcars
# ---- NOTE: ending dataset - mtcars__gear_is_5
# ---- NOTE: filter variable - gear
# ---- NOTE: filter variable value(s) - 5

##### starting dataset
str(mtcars)

##### unique values of starting dataset$filter
unique(mtcars$gear)

##### filters data into post-filter dataset
mtcars__gear_is_5 <- filter(mtcars, (gear == "5"))

##### turns post-filter dataset into data frame
mtcars__gear_is_5 <- data.frame(mtcars__gear_is_5)

##### post-filter dataset
str(mtcars__gear_is_5)

##### unique values of post-filter dataset$filter
unique(mtcars__gear_is_5$gear)

## regressions where data is filtered by gear

### list of filtered datasets
str(mtcars__gear_is_3)
str(mtcars__gear_is_4)
str(mtcars__gear_is_5)

#### when mtcars__gear_is_3 is dataset used
lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_3 <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars__gear_is_3)
summary(lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_3)

#### when mtcars__gear_is_4 is dataset used
lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_4 <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars__gear_is_4)
summary(lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_4)

#### when mtcars__gear_is_5 is dataset used
lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_5 <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars__gear_is_5)
summary(lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars__gear_is_5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you will be able to achieve you goal with something like this :

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
formulas <- paste0("lm(mpg ~ am, data = dt[gear == ", unique(dt[,gear]), "])" )
l <- lapply(formulas, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
```

and to see all models, just use :

```
l
```

or to see summary of one of the models :

```
summary(lm[[1]])
```

Comment: I think this works okay. I'm still new to R, so I ad a little trouble with this, but it seems to work okay. I did notice that the grouping variable level for the dt$gear had to be in numeric form. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `dplyr nest()`. See more info [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html).

```r
library(tidyverse,warn.conflict = F)
  
df <- mtcars %>% # Nest data by gear
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  nest()

df$data
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 12 x 10
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6 160     110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4
#>  2  21       6 160     110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4
#>  3  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     1
#>  4  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     2
#>  5  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     2
#>  6  19.2     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4
#>  7  17.8     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4
#>  8  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     1
#>  9  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     2
#> 10  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     1
#> 11  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     1
#> 12  21.4     4 121     109  4.11  2.78  18.6     1     1     2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 15 x 10
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     1
#>  2  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     2
#>  3  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     1
#>  4  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     4
#>  5  16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3
#>  6  17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3
#>  7  15.2     8  276.   180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3
#>  8  10.4     8  472    205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     4
#>  9  10.4     8  460    215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     4
#> 10  14.7     8  440    230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     4
#> 11  21.5     4  120.    97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     1
#> 12  15.5     8  318    150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     2
#> 13  15.2     8  304    150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     2
#> 14  13.3     8  350    245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     4
#> 15  19.2     8  400    175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  carb
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  26       4 120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     2
#> 2  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     2
#> 3  15.8     8 351     264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     4
#> 4  19.7     6 145     175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     6
#> 5  15       8 301     335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     8



mod <- function(x) {
  lm(mpg ~ am,data = x) # Create model
}

map(df$data, mod)
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ am, data = x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           am  
#>      21.050        5.225  
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ am, data = x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           am  
#>       16.11           NA  
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ am, data = x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           am  
#>       21.38           NA

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data,mod))

df[[3]]
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ am, data = x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           am  
#>      21.050        5.225  
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ am, data = x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           am  
#>       16.11           NA  
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ am, data = x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           am  
#>       21.38           NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>